# Display images from directory

Tags: c#, .net, loops, directory, picturebox

I have the following code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        MessageBox.Show(files.ElementAt(1).ToString());
        PictureBox[] cards = new PictureBox[files.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            cards[i] = new PictureBox();
            cards[i].BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images\\" + files[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images\\" + files[i]);
            cards[i].Padding = new Padding(0);
            cards[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            cards[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(card_click);
            cards[i].Size = new Size((int)(this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - 15, images.Height);
                images.Controls.Add(cards[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note:  "images" is a FlowLayoutPanel in my program's graphic designer. I use it to easily keep track of the images.

I'm trying to get it to display images of a few poker cards, from the directory. The directory is correct, the folder is there, and previous uses of the folder have worked; Form1 is the first form of the program, and "programdir" is:

```
public static string programdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Messageboxes seem to display the correct diagnostic information (folder location, card file names, even files.Count() seems to be correct), but I can't get any files displayed in pictureboxes. Any advice?

EDIT: Apparently, the line

```
MessageBox.Show(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images\\" + files[i]);
```

Does not run, ever, at all, even though

```
MessageBox.Show(files.ElementAt(1).ToString());
```

Does run. As well,

```
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

Only runs once, outputting "0" in a messagebox (since "i" is set to 0 initially), even though it should run 4 times, since the size of the array "files" is 4.

EDIT 2: The new code, which runs flawlessly, is:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri baseUri = new Uri(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images\\");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        MessageBox.Show(files.Count().ToString());
        PictureBox[] cards = new PictureBox[files.Count()];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            Uri completeUri = new Uri(baseUri, files[i]);
            try
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(completeUri.LocalPath);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                // remove this if you don't want to see the exception message
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                continue;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            cards[i] = new PictureBox();
            cards[i].BackgroundImage = bmp;
            MessageBox.Show(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images\\" + files[i]);
            cards[i].Padding = new Padding(0);
            cards[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            cards[i].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(card_click);
            cards[i].Size = new Size((int)(this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - 15, images.Height);
            cards[i].Visible = true;
                images.Controls.Add(cards[i]);
        }
    }
```

The try/catch block isn't mandatory because it doesn't catch any errors anymore, but I'm leading it just in case something else happens some time down the road. This code will grab all images from the folder (with the assumption that only image files are in the folder, which is a separate issue), display them, and bake you a cake all at once.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but have you tried `cards[i].Visible = true;`?

Comment: @Corey Yes, I've tried it; an interesting bit of info has also come to my attention, I'll edit my original question with the new info...

Comment: Maybe since this in only a sample of your code this isn't a real issue for you, but `Directory.GetFiles()` returns the full paths of files, not just their names. So your concatenation step would produce invalid paths. Also, I haven't seen this problem in a while (older versions of VS) but it used to be certain errors couldn't easily be caught in `Form_Load` and sometimes they just appeared to be swallowed. Try moving your code to a button click instead of form load to see if it is throwing an exception that you're just not seeing.

Comment: Ah, it's a silent exception issue.  The `new Bitmap()` call is failing, but the exception is being intercepted without being displayed.  Wrap the `for` loop in a `try...catch` block and see what exception you're getting.  And try examining the composed filename prior to calling `new Bitmap()` using it.

Comment: Indeed it was throwing an exception - the path name wasn't invalid in the usual sense, it was actually too long for the code to handle. Props to you guys for figuring that out, I've never come across this kind of error before.

Comment: Aww, I just about finished updating my answer to show how to get around the long path issue, and it turns out it was a problem with your code.  The `GetFiles` results ***already have the full path in them***.  You don't need to do *anything* with them to get a full path, it's already there.  Stop messing about with the URIs and just use the paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem appears to be that the path you are attempting to load from is invalid, because of some assumptions about the output of `Directory.GetFiles()`, combined with the fact that the exception you would normally expect to see is being silently dropped.

With that in mind, here's my take on a rewrite:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Form1.programdir + "\\card_images", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    foreach (var filename in files)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // remove this if you don't want to see the exception message
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            continue;
        }

        var card = new PictureBox();
        card.BackgroundImage = bmp;
        card.Padding = new Padding(0);
        card.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        card.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(card_click);
        card.Size = new Size((int)(this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - 15, images.Height);

        images.Controls.Add(card);
    }
}
```

I skipped creating an array since you're not keeping it anyway, and took out your diagnostic `MessageBox` calls.  This code should load any files it finds, ignoring any that it failed to load for whatever reason, and create a `PictureBox` for each one that loads successfully.

Incidentally, one of the possible reasons for failure is if there are any files in the `card_images` folder that can't be handled by the `Bitmap` class.  It's good, but it won't render an image from a document file or a DLL :P

Final thought: breakpoints and single-step debugging will definitely help you find the issues much faster.  Visual Studio Express is sufficient for the task if you don't have anything else.

---

Update: Dealing with long path names

Long story short, long filenames are a pain in the rear end.

And the long story....

After a bit of checking it seems that the .NET framework **by design** (see [this series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) from 2007) will not handle long path names.  The `\\?\` prefix is rejected by all .NET classes, and UNC paths in the form `//localhost/C$/...........` are also rejected if they exceed MAX_PATH characters in length.

There are only a few things you can do about this:

1. The solution suggested by the .NET designers is to get rid of the long paths by relocating the files to a shorter path.  *(In other words, don't even **try** to use long paths.)*
2. Create new versions of the `System.IO` classes with long path support.  *(Not for the faint of heart.)*
3. A variety of hacks abound, including [using the `DefineDosDevice` API](http://simoncropp.com/handlinglongpathsinnet) (the core of the old `subst` dos command) to map an available drive letter to some subset of the path that fits inside the MAX_PATH limit. *(Fun, but hacky.)*
4. Use the [`GetShortPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx) API function to turn a long path into an abbreviated version of itself using the 8.3 abbreviations created in the filesystem.

I'll focus on that last option.

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    const int MAX_PATH = 260;

    // Force unicode version to get long-path support
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetShortPathNameW(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
            string lpszLongPath,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
            StringBuilder lpszShortPath,
            uint cchBuffer
        );

    public static string ShortenPath(string longPath)
    {
        // check if path is already short enough
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(longPath) || longPath.Length <= MAX_PATH)
            return longPath;

        // Get short version of path 
        StringBuilder shortNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        uint result = GetShortPathNameW(@"\\?\" + longPath, shortNameBuffer, (uint)MAX_PATH);

        // result is length of returned path.  Must be >4 bytes to be valid
        if (result <= 4)
            return null;

        // Get result, removing "\\?\" prefix
        var res = shortNameBuffer.ToString().Substring(4);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Call `NativeMethods.ShortenPath` with a valid path of any length and it will try to shorten it for you if necessary.  Will fail on long paths if the file couldn't be found, and might return invalid results if the resultant shortened filename is greater than MAX_PATH characters in length... which means you have 27+ directories with long names in the path, which is pretty silly anyway :P

And of course now that you've posted your workaround... it turns out that the path isn't actually too long.  *sigh*  If you ever hit the path limit, this will still help.

Comment: Thanks - that was it! It's telling me the path name or filename are too long. How can I shorten it or bypass that error though? That seems like an odd error.

Comment: There's a limitation in the standard Windows API of `MAX_PATH` characters - usually 260 characters.  You can bypass that in some cases by specifying the path as a local UNC path, which has a limit of 32767 characters.  I'll update when I find a way to get this to work with the `Bitmap` constructor.

Comment: I got it - I'll update the question with the code that made it work. Many thanks for your help!